# Docker not binding to specified IP

Tags: docker, dokku

I've made the follow edit to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "ip" : "[ip address]"
}
```

To confirm, I inspect the network with `docker network inspect [id]`

```
"Options": {    
  "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "[ip address]",  
  "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
},
```

Yet somehow all containers are still responding to other ips on the server, not just the given IP.

How can I restrict `docker` to a specific ip?

NOTE:

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

> Or if you always want Docker port forwards to bind to one specific IP address, you can edit your system-wide Docker server settings and add the option --ip=IP_ADDRESS. Remember to restart your Docker server after editing this setting.

Answer (score 0):

The config file "/etc/docker/daemon.json" affects the docker daemon and not the container instances.

You have to configure your docker instance to bind just on the ip you want. 
For example with a direct run :

```
docker run --rm -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 nginx
```

This will make the container bind the port 80 only on the ip 127.0.0.1

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. There seems to way to do this as a default https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/ "Or if you always want Docker port forwards to bind to one specific IP address, you can edit your system-wide Docker server settings and add the option --ip=IP_ADDRESS."

Comment: You're right I didn't know that, sorry.
I tried modifying the /etc/docker/daemon.json with { "ip": "127.0.0.1" } and it worked after restarting the daemon. What version are you using?

Comment: 18.05.0-ce. I should mention that these container were setup using `dokku`

Comment: Don't know it, I can't help you any further sorry. I think dokku is setting the ip address the containers have to bind to, so docker is ignoring the default option you put in the config file.

Comment: That does make sense, it probably is. Thanks for your help